# Is it possible to make a search and replace in file-content on multiple network locations?

Tags: powershell, replace, visual-studio-code

I need to search for a string and then replace it with another in multiple files. Sound easy, but the hard part is that is that it's multiple files on multiple network locations. I've tried connecting to all of the locations at once with vscode and then using the built-in search and replace function. This allmost works, except when I get to big searches is seems to hang. 
I'm now looking for another, more stable, way to do this. Anybody got any ideas? I thought powershell could be a good competitor, but unfortunately I'm not that used to working with powershell. 
I found this guide and it's a bit like what I want, except I need to do it on multiple files at multiple locations at once.
https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/08/08/replace-text-with-powershell.aspx

I would settle with running one skript for each location since it's only < 20 locations to scan. But it needs to include subfolders.

Any tips are appreciated, thanks! :)

**Edit 1:**
The folder structure differs from location to location so its hard to say how it looks. But I can say that no location has a folder structure deeper than 15 steps. The text that I'm replacing are thumbprints of certificates stored in `.config` files. The files are between 100 and 1000 characters long and the thumbprints I'm replacing looks something like this `d2e8c58e5b34021671f2121483572f03f54ab9ae`

Comment: Your question is IMO way too broad, break it down into manageble parts and start coding if you get stuck some back and present a [mcve]. [SO] isn't a script writing service.

Comment: I have intentionally left this question a bit broad since I would like a broad answer for it. I don't want to narrow it down too much since I beleive that would only limit the answers.

Comment: You might get the opposite, why should potential answerers put more effort in your task than you seem to be willing to?

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that the different network locations are in trusted domains or at least part of the wmi trustedhosts. PowerShell remoting will also need to be enabled on all computers involved. Run *(In elevated PowerShell)* **Enable-PSRemoting -Force** to enable PowerShell Remoting

```
$command = { Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test\ -Include *.config -Name -Recurse | ForEach-Object {$configContent = Get-Content -Path $_ -Raw; $configContent.Replace("Old Value", "New Value") | Out-File -FilePath ($_.FullName) -Force } }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "TestServer1", "TestServer2", "etc..." -ScriptBlock $command
```

If you are not part of the domain but have a domain/server login, you will need to use the **-Credentials** switch on the **Invoke-Command** function. This will basically find all files that have the .config extension in any subfolders in the path, get the current content of the .config file, replace your value, and finally overwrite the existing config file. **WATCH OUT THOUGH** this will get ***EVERY .config*** file that is in that path. If you have more than one it will also grab it, but if it doesn't have the string it will just rewrite the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing an example of the folder structures and files this is quite hard to give a thorough answer on. However I would probably build a series of `ForEach` segments. For example:

```
ForEach ($Server in $Servers)

    {
        ForEach ($File in $Files)
            {
                Select-String -Path $File -Pattern "$ExampleString" 
            }
    }
```

Comment: The folder structure differs from location to location so its kind of hard to say. But I guess no location has a folder structure deeper than 15 steps. The text that I'm replacing are thumbprints of certificates stored in the .config files.

Comment: @wenzzzel You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55652949/edit) your question to contain additional/updated information, not stray it in comments.

Comment: I have added it to the post